# WinUI 3 - UWP - How to programmatically add or remove resource dictionaries

Tags: uwp, resourcedictionary, winui-3

In Xamarin Forms, you can interact with the Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries by doing Add or Remove of a newed-up resource dictionary xaml file class

```
ResourceDictionary myResourceDictionary = new MyResourceDictionary();

Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary );
```

or

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(myResourceDictionary );
```

and the application displays the changes.

How is this done in WinUI 3 - UWP?  I've tried doing the same thing in Page code-behind but changes don't happen as expected.

UserResourceDictionary.xaml appears as:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="UWPTestApp2.Resources.UserResourceDictionary">

<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Default"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="6"/>
</Style>
```

MainPage.xaml appears as:

```
<Page
x:Class="UWPTestApp2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Width="200"
Height="200"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Click="Button1_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

... and the Button1_Click callback appears as:

```
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserResourceDictionary _userResourceLibrary = new UserResourceDictionary();
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(_userResourceLibrary);
    }
```

Nothing is declared in the App.xaml file

When the Button1_Click function is executed, no visible changes happen with the button.

Comment: The code is not complete. Please share the code snippet about the ResourceDictionary and how do you use it so that we could reproduce this behavior within a blank app.

Comment: Updated description with code samples

Comment: Could you please share more details about how it works in Xamarin Forms? Where did you put the `UserResourceDictionary`? In the Forms project or the UWP project? In our  test, add the ResourceDictionary does not work in Xamarin UWP apps and normal UWP apps

Comment: To be clear, I had a SEPARATE Xamarin Forms application, where adding the UserResourceDictionary in the Button callback worked with no issues.  The code shown above is from a UWP application, and the Button callback does not work.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code that you used in Xamarin Forms application?

Comment: The Xamarin Forms application is very large.  Creating a small test application that includes the code above should work.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the code does not work in a Xamarin app and that's why I'm asking how do you use these code.